# How can I convince powershell (run through task scheduler) to find my network drive?

Tags: windows-7, powershell, task, scheduler

I have a simple powershell script on windows 7 that doesn't work properly. (this is not an issue on XP)

```
get-psdrive
```

When I run it directly, I get

```
  Name           Used (GB)     Free (GB) Provider      Root
----           ---------     --------- --------      ----
A                                      FileSystem    A:\
Alias                                  Alias
C                  12.30         11.60 FileSystem    C:\
cert                                   Certificate   \
D                                      FileSystem    D:\
Env                                    Environment
Function                               Function
HKCU                                   Registry      HKEY_CURRENT_USER
HKLM                                   Registry      HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
**Q                1486.63        289.41 FileSystem    Q:\**
Variable                               Variable
WSMan                                  WSMan
```

When I run this through task scheduler, I get

```
Name           Used (GB)     Free (GB) Provider      Root
----           ---------     --------- --------      ----
A                                      FileSystem    A:\
Alias                                  Alias
C                  12.30         11.60 FileSystem    C:\
cert                                   Certificate   \
D                                      FileSystem    D:\
Env                                    Environment
Function                               Function
HKCU                                   Registry      HKEY_CURRENT_USER
HKLM                                   Registry      HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
Variable                               Variable
WSMan                                  WSMan
```

Note that I'm missing my Q: drive. If there's any way to get this resolved, I'll be able to copy files there....

Comment: Sounds like a permissions issue - are you sure the user for the scheduled task has the correct permissions both for the file system AND for powershell?

Comment: Yes, I'm running as 'me' with 'highest privileges' checked as well... :(

Comment: Ugh... I've been digging over the weekend and found a lousy work-around. using "net use h: \\server\mount /user:domain/credentials password" will get it to work. Seriously? That's all I've got? It works, but now I've got username credentials in my script... Yes, I could use .net encryption, but really...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe before running get-psdrive in script, firstly do something like this:

```
$net = new-object -comobject Wscript.Network
$net.mapnetworkdrive("Q:","\\path\to\share",0,"domain\user","password")
```

and after doing your job (copying files..):

```
$net.removenetworkdrive("Q:")
```

Comment: Oh, I haven't spot your comment not-bob - this solution is like yours with net-use.

Comment: yes, your answer matches mine. I'm still mystified why it works differently, even when run as the same user. sigh... But in the interests of making this workaround more obvious, I'll mark your answer as the one I'm looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Network drives, and really all drive letters for that matter, are "mapped" to volumes for a given logon session. When you are creating a scheduled task to run it creates a new login session (even if you are currently logged in) and runs the scheduled task in that context. Thus, while you may be logged in and have a Q drive mapped - the second session that is running the task has a completely different environment, Windows is just nice enough to automatically map the C: (and other physical drives) for all sessions.

You shouldn't need to map a map a drive when using PowerShell, other than for perhaps convenience. Unlike the cmd.exe predecessor, PowerShell is perfectly happy to change the current directory to a UNC style path:

```
cd \\server\share\directory
```

Is it possible to accomplish what you need without mapping a drive at all? You have mentioned copying files - if the task is running with your credentials, and assuming you have permissions to the Q: drive (lets say \server\share), then your script should be able to do something like:

```
copy c:\logs\*.log \\server\share\logs
```

And work just fine without needing to map a drive.

Here is the complete command info for my test that worked. If your environment is different please note how. The task is configured to run as my domain account, only when I am logged in, highest privileges and configured for Windows 7/Server 2008 R2.

The action is to Start a program:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

Arguments

```
-command copy c:\logs\*.log \\server\share\logs
```

Comment: Sorry, but you could probably see my situation by mimicking my environment. Powershell run through task scheduler on Windows 7 with a remote share. What you are proposing doesn't work as a scheduled task using task scheduler, I've tried... :(

Comment: Your opening paragraph that explains the nuts of bolts of what the OS is doing was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There is a hack if you don't want to have a password in the script, which I prefer to avoid :

- Open your folder with sufficient privileges (domain user for example)
- Open a powershell as Administrator and an make a symlink from UNC to local path

  New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -Path "C:\LocalTemp\" -Value "\unc"
- You can now use the UNC path in your powershell script directly, it will open it with the credential provided in the scheduled task.

There is probably some issues with credentials in scheduled tasks, however this is still better in my opinion than password in clear or pseudo obfuscated in scripts.