# Equivalent of net use \\server_name\share_name /delete in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, network-share, net-use

does anybody know the equivalent in PowerShell of the following windows command:

```
net use \\server_name\share_name /delete
```

I'd like to disconnect from the shares from powershell, included the ones that are not mapped as shared drives.

Comment: Maybe answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055704/how-can-i-convince-powershell-run-through-task-scheduler-to-find-my-network-dr/4097398#4097398 could somehow guide you.

Comment: why not just use "net use \\servername\share\ /delete" ? powershell is a shell, not a replacement operating system.

Comment: @x0n because of a bug in ps that raises an exception when you call poweshell redirecting the standard error in standard output with 2&>1 : have a look here: http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2008/07/30/workaround-the-os-handles-position-is-not-what-filestream-expected/ . To avoid the problem I call from powershell a bat that calls the net use redirecting the standard error in the standard output, otherwise I would get the error. My ps script is called by a scheduler that calls it with 2&>1 over which I don't have control, and the ps does some reasoning to find the shares it has to disconnect.

Comment: @mic.sca ok, I've answered with the equivalent WMI.

Answer (score 0):

WMI should do the trick:

```
ps> get-wmiobject -computer server -class win32_share -credential $creds | `
    where-object { $_.name -eq "sharedfolder" } | foreach-object  { $_.delete() }
```

Comment: this deletes the share itself, while net use /delete is called by the client to disconnect from a share